# On radio clcik show div when clcik on other radio show another div with java script pure function

Tags: javascript

[image]

here is the view of my code

i dont have any idea

Comment: Please see example here https://codepen.io/dhanushbadge/pen/AYRWLW

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: dear ravi ; in my case i have 2 radio and 2 dive so it is not working as per my requirement

Comment: this is not an perfect code you just need to take a reference from this..you can only get how to do with which functions etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code

```js
function show1(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='block'; document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='none';
}
function show2(){ 
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>How many check boxes do you want when clicked on a radio button?</p>
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igotnone" onclick="show1();" />
First
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show2();" />
Second
<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr><p>First div</p>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr><p>Second div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Thansk one last thing if we want one div is by default checked and show div first time when page is load

Comment: remove class hide from that div which you have to display by default and if this code is helpful to you than approve this answer

Comment: dear it is not working